# Moving WP install from local to live, what about wp_posts GUID?

Tags: customization, guids

Done this before and i am still wondering what to do with the `wp_posts => guid content`, which has reference to http://localhost

But at wordpress.org [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/#important-guid-note) it clearly states:

> Never, ever, change the contents of the GUID column, under any
> circumstances.

But as i understand it is just to unique identify  your posts globally. But as more people would have http://localhost in their guid.

So can i safely replace http://localhost with http://example.com ?

regards

Comment: here is the answer to change guid from localhost to live domain ->
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/238086/200021

Comment: this worked for me `sudo nvim ~/backup_wp.sql`                                                                                                                  
 ```:%s/[old_domain]/[new_domain]/g```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"GUID" stands for "Globally Unique Identifier" mainly used by feeds to tell if that specific post was shown on the feed before or not, even if you change domains.

When developing on local host and the moving to live (+1 just for that BTW) and no feed reader/burner has read your feeds and only if that is the case it's OK to change it and start fresh on your new live host.

Comment: tx, still not able to move from local to live in 5 min, ;) For others i used
`UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'http://localhost', 'http://www.mydomain.com');`

Comment: Using `sed` on a dump to replace hosts will ensure that all your menus, options, etc. are ready for production as well.

Comment: Yes, I also normally dump the DB, then globally replace in the dump before restoring it. I also just noticed that under the [Codex advice on moving multi-site installs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Multisite), there's now a link to [a specialised search and replace tool](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) that copes with safely replacing in PHP serialised DB data, specifically for doing things like this.

Comment: @Soulseekah btw what is sed ??

Comment: @alex http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed

Comment: The [`wp` command line tool](http://wp-cli.org/) is great for this: `wp --path=path/to/wp search-replace 'dev-domain.com' 'www.production-domain.com'` If you want to avoid changing the guid field, then add `--skip-columns=guid`.

Comment: It would be nice if the `guid` was not the url as the guid is internally also used for creating links. Which kind of sucks when transferring site from http -> https.